# My script runs perfectly until I wrap it in this if (screen.width < 980) { } statement to check screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

@John

Ok, I had the greater than sign mixed up. The simple things....What I'm looking to do is have codeMagic() run on page load only if the browser.width() > 941px, if the page is resized < 941px stop codeMagic() from running. If the page is again resized & the browser width is >= 941px turn codeMagic() on. Then of course if the page loads less than 941px don't run codeMagic(), but keep the resizing awareness.

Here is my example code:

CSS:

```
<style>
    body { margin: 0; }
    footer { padding: 10px; margin: 10px; height: 100%; } 
  </style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="home">home!</div>
<footer>footer!</footer>

<script src='lib/js/vendor/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='../den.js'></script>
```

JS:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) { 
// set element height based on 'window height' - 'footer height' 

function codeMagic() {

    var docHeight = parseInt($( window ). height());     
    var footerHeight = parseInt($( 'footer' ).outerHeight( true ));
    var homeHeight = +docHeight - +footerHeight + 'px';

        $( 'body #home' ).height(homeHeight);
        console.log( homeHeight, footerHeight);         
};

if (jQuery(window).width() >= 941) {  

codeMagic(); // init codeMagic

//Set codeMagic to run on browser resize
$( window ).resize( function() { 

    codeMagic();

    });
   }
});
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: what is the screen width? `console.log(jQuery(window).width())`

Comment: @steven I received this 
line 1: '1284'
line 2:'undefined'

Comment: 1284 is greater than 900, so it makes sense that your code's not running. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JohnFlatness Question edited.

Comment: Just making, sure, did you pass `$` to your `ready` event, like so: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your resize event never gets triggered if the browser is bigger than `941 px` on DOM init because you didn't bind it than. You need to change it like the following:

```
if (jQuery(window).width() >= 941) {  
  codeMagic(); // init codeMagic
}


//afterwards bind to the resize event
$( window ).resize( function() { 
  //check size again
  if (jQuery(window).width() >= 941) {  
    codeMagic();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you put the check _inside_ `codeMagic`??